# React Native: Bringing DATA from flatlist to the modal it is assigned too

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-flatlist

Each item in my Flatlist has a button that opens a modal and I want to display the unique data from that item into my modal, the code below is where I've got up to so far. I just can't seem to get it to work! Currently when the modal loads it is empty with a close button.

Could someone let me know what am I missing or needs to be done for this?

I appreciate the help!

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from "react-native";

import { Colors } from "../colors/Colors";

const DATA = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Calves and Hamstrings: one",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S1.png"),
    modalTitle: "Calves and Hamstrings: one",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Adductors: one",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S2.png"),
    modalTitle: "Adductors: one",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "Adductors: two",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S3.png"),
    modalTitle: "Adductors: two",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    title: "Hip Flexors",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S4.png"),
    modalTitle: "Hip Flexors",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    title: "Calves and Hamstrings: two",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S5.png"),
    modalTitle: "Calves and Hamstrings: two",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    title: "Quads",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S6.png"),
    modalTitle: "Quads",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    title: "Calves and Hamstrings: three",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S7.png"),
    modalTitle: "Calves and Hamstrings: three",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    title: "Glutes (Bum)",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S8.png"),
    modalTitle: "Glutes (Bum)",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "9",
    title: "Abs",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S9.png"),
    modalTitle: "Abs",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    title: "Lats (Sides)",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S10.png"),
    modalTitle: "Lats (Sides)",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "11",
    title: "Deltoid (Shoulder)",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S11.png"),
    modalTitle: "Deltoid (Shoulder)",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "12",
    title: "Triceps",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S12.png"),
    modalTitle: "Triceps",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
  {
    id: "13",
    title: "Pecs (Chest)",
    section: "Stretches",
    image: require("../assets/S13.png"),
    modalTitle: "Pecs (Chest)",
    modalDesc:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
  },
];

export default function StretchesScreen() {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [modalDesc, setModalDesc] = useState([]);
  const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] = useState("");

  const Item = ({ title, image, section, modalTitle, modalDesc }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Image source={image} style={styles.exerciseImage} />
      <View style={styles.detailSection}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.section}>{section}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.viewButton}
        onPress={() => {
          openSettingsModal(modalTitle, modalDesc);
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.viewText}>View</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} image={item.image} section={item.section} />
  );

  const openSettingsModal = (modalTitle, modalDesc) => {
    setModalTitle(modalTitle);
    setModalDesc(modalDesc);
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.tabBackground}>
        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>EXERCISES: STRETCHES</Text>
      </View>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>{modalTitle}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>{modalDesc}</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3" }}
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  tabBackground: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    width: "100%",
    height: "10%",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  subTitle: {
    position: "absolute",
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 10,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    width: "90%",
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Colors.greyLight,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  exerciseImage: {
    width: "20%",
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
  },
  detailSection: {
    width: "50%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    left: 0,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  section: {
    fontSize: 10,
  },
  viewButton: {
    height: 40,
    width: "30%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Colors.greyMedium,
    borderRadius: 3,
  },
  viewText: {
    left: 0,
  },
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 22,
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  openButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#F194FF",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2,
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  modalText: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need multiple states to pass the selected item details, you stick to one variable which is selectedItem and another to control the visibility of the modal.
And you can chose to store either the item or the selected it in the state. Also as you are not having any logic in renderItem a separate function is not required, you can do it inline. You can see the code below.

```
export default function StretchesScreen() {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState({});

  const Item = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Image source={item.image} style={styles.exerciseImage} />
      <View style={styles.detailSection}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.section}>{item.section}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.viewButton}
        onPress={() => {
          openSettingsModal(item);
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.viewText}>View</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

  const openSettingsModal = (item) => {
    setCurrentItem(item);
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.tabBackground}>
        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>EXERCISES: STRETCHES</Text>
      </View>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
        }}>
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>{currentItem.modalTitle}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>{currentItem.modalDesc}</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: '#2196F3' }}
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}>
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```